# Unable to begin a distributed transaction using Entiy Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ibm-midrange

I'm having the following error executing this piece of code:

```
private bool _updateList(SysInfo _sysInfo, List<pList> _pList)
{
    try
    {

        foreach (var p in _pList)
        {
            _context.spUpdatePListApprovalFlow(p.countryID, _sysInfo.User.JobRoleID, p.src, p.id, p.status, _sysInfo.User.Username);
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) //debug only
    {
        throw; //throws error to the main try catch
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "AS400_LINKEDSRV" was unable to begin a distributed
>   transaction.

However, everything works fine when I run the Stored Procedure in SQL Management Studio:

```
exec [dbo].[spUpdatePListApprovalFlow]
        @CountryID  = 123456,
        @UserTypeID = 23456,
        @Src = 1,
        @Id = '123456789',
        @Status = 30,
        @Username  = 'username'
```

I'm tired of digging for an answer nothing works... Few things I've tried:

- SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
- insert multiple transactions in the stored procedure

This sp has 2 sub stored procedures on it. One that writes into a table of the application's database, and another that updates a table in as400.

Answer (score 3):

In EF6 stored procedures are called in an explicit transaction, by default.  You can turn this off for a particular DbContext instance by changing its configuration after creating it, or for all instances of a DbContext type by changing it in the constructor.  EG

```
    using (var db = new Db())
    {
        db.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
        //. . .
    }
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.ensuretransactionsforfunctionsandcommands

Comment: Please, can you put the link of the documentation saying that EF6 calls stored procedures in an explicit transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after half a day trying to solve this I've finally solved it.

**Resolution**

> Downgraded from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework 5 and the
>   distribuited transactions error has gone.

Just **pay attention**, if you're going to do this, you have to change some usings in your code. ( in auto generated code in the Data Model as well)

**EF 6** uses

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects
```

**EF 5** uses

```
using System.Data.Objects;
```

Comment: Now that you've confirmed that a different version of EF behaves differently you can ask another very good question about EF and find the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need distributed transactions you can try to disable them in the settings of the linked server:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
    @server=N'AS400_LINKEDSRV', 
    @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', 
    @optvalue=N'false'
```

Comment: I'm not DBA, I have admin permissions in my DB only. However will this solve the problem? Can you please explain what is the impact of turning this off? If rly needed I can ask them to do so.

Comment: This is changing the settings of the linked server `AS400_LINKEDSRV` in your SQL Server instance. It is not touching the remote AS400 server.

Comment: If distributed transactions are enabled, if everything is configured and working, then transaction spans across both servers as if it was a single server. If transaction is not distributed, then your SQL Server is responsible for wrapping only local changes into a transaction and remote server is responsible for its own changes. It is possible that changes one server will be persisted and changes on another server not. Whether this is acceptable in your case depends on what your stored procedures do.

Comment: Another question that came up, my collegue in another project is doing exactly what I'm doing but he's using an older version of the Entity Framework (4.0), I'm using version 6 do you think there might be a problem with the connector due its version?

Comment: Sorry, @BrunoRodrigues, I've never used Entity Framework. Of course, since the query runs fine in SSMS the problem is with your C# code and/or Entity Framework options. Maybe EF starts some extra transaction that contains not just this SP, but something else, which causes transaction to be promoted to distributed. Maybe EF by default starts all transactions as distributed and you see the problem only when you actually use two different servers. You can try to dig into EF settings, but I can't help with EF. Maybe somebody else will add an answer specific for EF.

Comment: Thx for your help  @VladimirBarov. Anyway the problem was EF I've downgraded from 6 to 5 and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [Microsoft page on Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine).

Your System Administrator and/or DBA will probably need to make changes to address the missing linked server definition to your AS/400 server.

Another possible issue is that the AS/400 server (from IBM) lacks software support for the OLE DB data sources. This too would be something that the System Administration staff may need to address.